# How to set up a default program opening an unknown file extension?

Tags: finder, applications, file-extensions

I tried to open a file with an extension name of adb in Finder (to be precise, PathFinder).
When I clicked the file, vi editor is activated to open the adb file. I didn't do anything with the adb file, so my guess is that vi editor changed the system setup to open it whenever unknown file format is opened.

How can I change this behavior? I want to open TextMate as a default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/780/problem-with-always-open-with-in-os-x/1432#1432) answer which points you to [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) so you can toy with extensions and default apps.

Answer (score 4):

**Finder Directions:**

Click a file of that type. Press `cmd-i`. Reveal the Open With: tab of the Get Info window that appears. Select the app you want. Click the Change All button below that menu.

Now, all files of the type you opened will open with the application you selected.

Comment: I wanted to know how to open TextMate even though I **don't** have the setup. I guess there should be some system level configuration necessary.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say that you don't have the setup?

Comment: So, you should be able to use the process I described to restore TextMate as the default. You could also check in vi editor's prefs to see if it's got an option for this.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Quesiton is about any unknown file type, not a specific one.