# VMWare Fusion is opening .docx files in Wordpad

Tags: virtualization, vmware, ms-office

I enabled the VMWare Fusion setting `Open your Mac files and web links using Windows Applications`. When I double click a .docx file in Finder, it launches Wordpad in the virtual machine, instead of Word. If I open the file again, it launches Word. If I launch it a third time, it opens Wordpad. It keeps alternating between these two programs.

On Windows, I tried right-clicking the file and going to the "Open With" command. It lists both Microsoft Office Word and WordPad as Recommended Programs. There doesn't seem to be an option to remove WordPad from this list.

When I launch the .docx file from inside Windows, it always opens it up with Word, leading me to believe that this is a VMWare Fusion bug and not a Windows bug.

Is there any way to have .docx files only open up in Word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these two questions:

- [Problem with "Always Open With" in OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/780/problem-with-always-open-with-in-os-x)
- [How to setup a default program opening an unknown file extension?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6387/how-to-setup-a-default-program-opening-an-unknown-file-extension)

It sounds to me as if the correct application will launch once you tell OS X which application it should use.

[image: open with]